# Is there a way to view a pivot table in compact form in Google Sheets?

Tags: pivot-table, google-sheets-api

In Microsoft Excel, you can view a pivot table in compact form by going to Design > Report Layout > Show in Compact Form. This makes it so the row fields all show up in the same column instead of separate columns. Is there a way to do this in Google Sheets?